# Azure - ARM CustomScriptExtension behind web proxy

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

We have a custom script stored on an Azure Storage Account and we want to run it as part of the Windows VM provisioning process through **CustomScriptExtension**. Unfortunately VM doesn't have direct access to the Internet and must go through a web proxy.

What is the best approach to handle such situation?

I've added powershell script to setup proxy as part of the **commandToExecute**, but this is executed after ARM tries to download script defined in **fileUris**, so fetching of fileUris fails (because proxy isn't set yet).

Also I was considering using of DSC before **CustomScriptExtension**, but again - to download the configuration I would need to have proxy configured already.

Using two **CustomScriptExtension**s apparently is not an option, since only the first one is executed by the system (which seems to be 'per design').

Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: As you said both of the DSC and custom script need the VM access the Internet. Have you consider using the powershell to directly connect to the VM and send command to the VM? If you using this, you needn't enable the proxy. You could just change the send arm template powershell command. You could directly get the command from the blob then send these command directly to the azure. About how to do it, you could refer to this [article](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-Use-a-PowerShell-59b2e28c).

Comment: Well, this is the approach that we use currently, but I'd like to put as much post-provisioning logic into the ARM template to fully automate instance provisioning process...

Comment: Another way, you could firstly enable the VM access the internet, you could set a public ip in the config in the arm template. Then you could download the script. At last  change the setting to make the VM don't access the internet.

Comment: Well, this approach is not possible because of security requirements :)